# destroySubcontext failing with NameNotFoudException

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I am trying to understand under what conditions `destroySubContext` fails in Tomcat. I’m trying to destroy `Context` which I had created, because of which I’m unable to `createContext` the next time I start the service.  My code is below :

```
  private Context srvCtx;
  public void init(ServletConfig servletconfig) throws ServletException {
      super.init(servletconfig);
      Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
      srvCtx = initCtx.createSubcontext("myapp");
  }

  public void destroy() 
  {
      try
      {
          if (srvCtx != null)
          {
              srvCtx.destroySubcontext("myapp");
              srvCtx.close();                                                   
          }
      }
      catch(NamingException e)
      {
          log_.error(new LogQueueMessageStructure("Couldn't unbind the context",3016),e);
      }

  }
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the context as a subcontext of `initCtx`:

```
srvCtx = initCtx.createSubcontext("myapp");
```

When you are destroing it however it seems like you are trying to destroy it as a subcontext of `srvCtx`.

```
srvCtx.destroySubcontext("myapp");
```

The myapp context is not a subcontext of `srvCtx`, it is a subcontext of `initCtx`. It should work better with

```
initCtx.destroySubcontext("myapp");
```